# gem spring-commands-rspec don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rspec, spring-gem

It seems a little strange, but gem `spring-commands-rspec` doesnt' work for me. Has somebody else met this strange behavior of this gem?

I've installed both `spring (1.3.5)` and `spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)`
And it seems I've met the troubles with run spring server for rspec. Please review the log

```
sergey@Pisuk:~/projects/fasteria$ time bin/rake db:migrate

real    0m2.013s
user    0m0.092s
sys 0m0.008s
sergey@Pisuk:~/projects/fasteria$ time bin/rake db:migrate

real    0m0.304s
user    0m0.087s
sys 0m0.008s

# it's worked

sergey@Pisuk:~/projects/fasteria$ time bin/rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb 
...

Finished in 1.1 seconds (files took 3 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures

real    0m4.274s
user    0m0.087s
sys 0m0.008s
sergey@Pisuk:~/projects/fasteria$ time bin/rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb 
...

Finished in 1.12 seconds (files took 2.98 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures

real    0m4.261s
user    0m0.088s
sys 0m0.008s
# doesn't work
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  ...
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I use `rvm -v 1.26.11`, `ruby -v 2.2.1p85`, `rails -v 4.2.0`, ubuntu 14.04.

Here is output of `sprng status` command:

```
Spring is running:

20677 spring server | fasteria | started 7 mins ago
20685 spring app    | fasteria | started 7 mins ago | development mode                                             
21872 spring app    | fasteria | started 6 mins ago | test mode
```

What's going wrong? P.S I have ran `spring stop` a lot of times

**UPDATED ADD SPRING LOG**

Usual rake command log

```
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22694] [server] accepted client
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22694] [server] running command rake
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22965] [client] sending command
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22697] [application:development] got client
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22697] [application:development] forked 22967
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22694] [application_manager:development] got worker pid 22967
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22965] [client] got pid: 22967
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22697] [application:development] 22967 exited with 0
[2015-05-06 11:00:02 +0300] [22965] [client] got exit status 0
```

Rspec log

```
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22694] [server] accepted client
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22694] [server] running command rspec
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22814] [client] sending command
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22756] [application:test] got client
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22756] [application:test] forked 22816
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22694] [application_manager:test] got worker pid 22816
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22814] [client] got pid: 22816
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22694] [server] accepted client
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22694] [server] running command rake
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22821] [client] sending command
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22756] [application:test] got client
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22756] [application:test] forked 22823
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22694] [application_manager:test] got worker pid 22823
[2015-05-06 10:57:56 +0300] [22821] [client] got pid: 22823
[2015-05-06 10:57:58 +0300] [22756] [application:test] 22823 exited with 0
[2015-05-06 10:57:58 +0300] [22821] [client] got exit status 0
[2015-05-06 10:58:00 +0300] [22756] [application:test] 22816 exited with 0
[2015-05-06 10:58:00 +0300] [22814] [client] got exit status 0
```

Comment: P.S. Issue at github repo: https://github.com/jonleighton/spring-commands-rspec/issues/32

Comment: Who created the /bin/rspec? It might be this bintstub that is not compatible with spring. Try `bundle exec spring rspec` versus `bundle exec rspec` to see if it works.

Comment: What does the Spring log file show? (see https://github.com/rails/spring#troubleshooting)

Comment: @berkes no, it still take 2 seconds for load (instead of original 4 seconds), but it takes too much. Normal time for loading is less than a half second.

Comment: Try bundle update spring

Comment: @Zippo9 tried that. No success